# I want to swap ComboBoxes selected items by clicking a button

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jcombobox

I am doing a conversor in NetBeans, the final objective is to say like "I want to know how many 50ft are in meters" and the program will tell me that.

Im using ComboBoxes with the names (like meters, jardas, feets etc) and between them i've put a ToggleButton, that button is to make the selected items in ComboBoxes (1 and 2) swap with each other but i dont know how to make that.

I have the following code:

```
if(jToggleButton1.isSelected()){
        i = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
        i2 = jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex();
        jComboBox1.(i dont know if there is any propriety to do this) = i2;
        jComboBox2.SelectedIndex() = i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of the documentation turns up [JComboBox#setSelectedIndex(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex(int))

```
jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(i2);
jComboBox2.setSelectedIndex(i);
```